# What is the history of number theory?

Tags: mathematics

Numbers were introduced in our lives far before we had the capability to understand their beauties. But as mathematics aspirant I really want to know how they all evolved and in what way number theory took its own path. May be the answer will be too descriptive,  So any link or book will work. Please if anybody know as such link and book refer it  (except Wikipedia).

Comment: This seems extremely (overly so!) broad. I think you need to focus the question a bit to restrict to either a certain period or a certain geographical area, for this question to be a bit more useful. Coincidentally, I do know of a little [book by Weil](http://www.amazon.com/Number-Theory-Approach-Hammurapi-Birkh%C3%A4user/dp/0817645659) that may interest you.

Comment: And yeah it is and actually I don't know what I don't want to know, I want to know from the beginning I guess so posted :(

Comment: Weil's book requires a familiarity with number theory already to appreciate what he is saying. Dickson wrote a 3-volume "History of the Theory of Numbers," which is more of a laundry list of what has been done up until the early 20th century rather than a thoughtful analysis of the work.

Comment: Ok. I am not completely unfamiliar neither an expert. I have studied David Burton's book of number theory will it be okay for me to study it?

Comment: Just get a copy from the library and try.

Comment: There will be parts of Weil's book that are hard if you do not know some algebraic geometry. An historically-oriented textbook on number theory is Jay Goldman's " The Queen of Mathematics: A Historically Motivated Guide to Number Theory."

Comment: Ok. I will try it. Then according to it I will learn topics needed for it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very comprehensive (several volumes) History of number theory by Dickson, https://archive.org/details/historyoftheoryo01dick
Here is a much shorter and more modern one:

Weil, André
Number theory. An approach through history from Hammurapi to Legendre. Reprint of the 1984 edition.
Basel: Birkhäuser (ISBN 978-0-8176-4565-6/pbk; 978-0-8176-4571-7/ebook). xxii, 376 p. EUR 34.90/net; SFR 59.90 (2007).